# using flask variables in html templates

Tags: python, flask

When I try to use a varible from a url argument the text disappears, here's the app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.abspath('templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath('static')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=STATIC_DIR)

@app.route('/<string:name>')
def home(name):
     return render_template('index.html', variable=name)
```

Here's what I am doing in the index.html file in templates folder:

```
<body>
<h1 class="header">Hello {{ name }}</h1>
<h3>Attention! This is a testing website with learning purpouses.</h3>
</body>
```

But when I run the app.py no error is displayed but it doesnt display the Hello {{ name }} line

Comment: Change `variable=name` to `name=name` in your python code or change `{{ name }}` to `{{ variable }}` in `index.html` file.

Comment: thanks, why isnt it variable?

Comment: `variable=name` means that you have a variable called `variable` in `index.html` file and you're giving it name's value. so when you put `{{ variable }}` in your `index.html` file, it will be replaced by it's value which is name's value here, since you said `variable=name`.

Comment: you can follow this simple rule : always write jinja variables on the left side and python variables on the right of the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this since you have assigned your name value to variable in your code :

```
<body>
<h1 class="header">Hello {{ variable }}</h1>
<h3>Attention! This is a testing website with learning purpouses.</h3>
</body>
```